# Filter expression '1' does not evaluate to a Boolean term

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, dataview

Filter expression '1' does not evaluate to a Boolean term. how to solve this error .when i click button only this error came

```
public DataSet Fill_Dataset()
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    con = new SqlConnection(str);
    con.Open();
    cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_new", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(ds);

    DataView dv = ds.Tables[1].DefaultView;

    if(ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count>1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;i++ )
        {
            DataRow dr = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i];
            DataTable dt1;
            dv.RowFilter=dr["country_id"].ToString();
            dt1 = dv.ToTable();
            ds.Tables.Add(dt1);
        }
    }
    return ds;
}

protected void excel_generation_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Export_Excel();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}

void Export_Excel()
{
    con = new SqlConnection(str);
    con.Open();
    DataSet ds = Fill_Dataset();

    using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
    {
        wb.Worksheets.Add(ds);
        wb.Style.Alignment.Horizontal = XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Center;
        wb.Style.Font.Bold = true;
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Summary_Rpt.xlsx");

        using (MemoryStream MyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            wb.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream);
            MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When does this error happen? At which line? What are you trying to do in order to cause this error? Dumping a series of methods on here and telling us that it's generating an error does not help us solve your problem. Be more specific.

Comment: I guess your Dataview filter is wrong. Check with dv.RowFilter="country_id >0";

Comment: here i used two table table 1 and table 2 .one stored in data row

Comment: this dr only i mapped row filter

Comment: i used to two table table...my stored procedure 

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_new]

AS
BEGIN
 declare @sql varchar(max)
 SET NOCOUNT ON;

 select @sql='select * from country;select * from state'
 exec(@sql)
 print(@sql)

END

Answer (score 0):

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataSet dstemp = new DataSet();

```
    con = new SqlConnection(str);
    con.Open();
    cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_new", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(ds);

    DataView dv = ds.Tables[1].DefaultView;

    if(ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count>1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            DataRow dr = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i];

            dv.RowFilter = "country_id = " + dr["country_id"];

            dstemp.Tables.Add(dv.ToTable(dr["country_name"].ToString()));
        }
    }
    return dstemp;
```